# Why rounding numbers in python gives different answers

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I have a code block:

```
round(4.5)
round(5.5)
```

When I run the code above, I get:

```
4
6
```

I expect the round to round the numbers up when the decimal is >5. Why round works differently for `4.5` and `5.5`

Comment: AKA Banker's rounding or Gaussian rounding

Comment: Please remember to check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round). This behavior is documented.